# How can I continous deploy on jenkins, but only when a particular branch is pushed to?

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, continuous-deployment

I read an article describing Continuous Deployment with jenkins thusly:

1. Create a 'test' job that runs your tests.
2. Create a 'deploy' job that deploys your app.
3. Make the 'test' job trigger 'deploy' on successful build.

I can do that just fine.  However, I have a generic 'test' job right now the runs tests for any branch that I push.  Is there a way to make it only trigger the 'deploy' job if I pushed to the 'production' branch?

Otherwise, I can always add a second 'test-production' job that only triggers when I push to production, and it triggers deploy afterwards...but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: What version control system do you use?

Comment: git.  By 'deploy' I really just mean 'execute another job' because I can take it from there.

Comment: could you add a link to the article... were all dying of curiosity!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative setup is to use [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) for deployment.

The [jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RunDeck+Plugin) has a feature that will trigger a deployment based on a SCM commit message:

> The "tag" field is used to perform "on-demand" job scheduling on RunDeck : if the value is not empty, we will check if the SCM changelog (= the commit message) contains the given tag, and only schedule a job execution if it is present. For example you can set the value to "#deploy". Note that if this value is left empty, we will ALWAYS schedule a job execution.

So you can configure rundeck to trigger a Jenkins test after every successful deploy. And control those deployments, using commit messages in the code.

Comment: Thanks, but rundeck's overkill for my needs.  I already have a single command I need to run in a shell script, in the event that the production branch was pushed to.  I'm thinking that this is what I want perhaps? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin